# How to Return Parse Query results to view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, view, parse-platform, return

I am using Parse javascript sdk, I am trying to query for all results within a specific classname, then return those results as a list of individual elements to my view.

**example:**

```
 query.find({

   $rootScope.$apply(function () {

    //test 
    console.log(results[0].get("playerName"));

      //loop results
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
      { 

          blogs.push({
              title : results[i].get('playerName'),
              post : results[i].get('personalityType')
              });
       }

  //receive all blog objects in console
  console.log(blogs);
  
 
  //now try to display to view/page here
  document.write(blogs);
```

The major issue is, I get an [object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],[object, Object],... when I try to display to view from document.write(blogs);

How do I get into these objects?

> blogs.title
>
> blogs["title"]
>
> blogs[0]

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get first value

```
blogs[0].title


    query.find({
$rootScope.$apply(function () {

    //test 
    console.log(results[0].get("playerName"));

      //loop results
      for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
      { 
        blogs[i]={}
        blogs[i].title = results[i].get('playerName');
        blogs[i].post  results[i].get('personalityType')

       }

  //receive all blog objects in console
  console.log(blogs);


  //now try to display to view/page here
  document.write(blogs);
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick response but it gave me more [object, Object]s except for the last one which was correct for once.

Comment: try this console.log(blogs); try copy and paste here form console to see it

Comment: dont put  document.write in loop this will show you only last result.

Comment: Sorry still nothing... I am currently using ionic framework + angularjs with parse so it is very picky on what it takes.

Comment: check this link i hope explain the logic behind it http://jsfiddle.net/DeveloperH/ca0xnpvu/1/

Comment: WOW! You solved it! Thank You! I have been working on this for the past 6 hours thinking I could fix it.. Nicely Done!

Comment: please rate my answer

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it did the trick! Thank You, Take a look below! I modified your response and solved most of my problems.

```
//Loops through all results
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) 
{ 
   //writes all results to page 
   document.write(blogs[i].title + " ");
   document.write(blogs[i].post + '</br>');
}
```

Although how can I get rid of the document.write in the loop?

I have already tried

> document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML